how to write javascript code that automates searches on bing?
i'm a regular user of microsoft rewards, and one major way to get points is to search around thirty unique queries on bing. each search has to have around seven seconds of time in between for it to count towards point progress. normally i have a loop timer going and just search random letters. like d (seven seconds) s (seven seconds) d (seven seconds) s and so on until the search bar looks like dsdsdsdsds dsdsdsdsds dsdsdsdsds lol!! i want to make this process easier thru a tampermonkey javascript script but i only have limited knowledge in python. can anyone give me a nudge in the right direction of what functions or lines to look into? thanks for any help! i'm not sure where to start.

You don't need Python to create Tampermonkey scripts. To run Javascript code on interval please use link.
const t = setInterval(() => {...}, 7000) will run the code inside the curly brackets every 7000 milliseconds which is 7 seconds.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
